# catchError is not found in Observable<Response>

Tags: http, angular6, rxjs6

I am attempting to catch errors from a HTTP request and based on error code I am displaying error messages to the user.To achieve this I am using the catchError operator from rxjs.

But I get this error which states **Property 'catchError' does not exist on type Observable < Response >**

Follwing is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
"@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"rxjs": "^6.0.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.26"
```

Following are the imports I have used in the service I am implementing to handle the http requests.

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '../../../node_modules/@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AppError } from './../common/app-error';
import { NotFoundError } from '../common/not-found-error';
```

This is the function which i delete a post from the server and return a custom error for expected and unexpected errors to my component.

```
deletePost(id:number){
return this.http.delete(this._url+"/"+id).catchError(
  (error:Response)=>{
    if(error.status===404){
      return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError());
    }
    return Observable.throw(new AppError(error));
  }
);
```

}

But when I try to delete a post I get the following error.

```
this.http.delete(...).catchError is not a function
```

I referred the following [API for rxjs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError) , in there as well according to my understanding catchError function expects an Observable as input. If anyone can help me resolve this issue I would highly appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to use pipe() operator before I can use operators like catchError from rxjs 6 onwards. Therefore the code should be modified like below.

```
deletePost(id:number){
return this.http.delete(this._url+"/"+id)
.pipe(
  catchError(
    (error:Response)=>{
      if(error.status===404){
        return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError());
      }
      return Observable.throw(new AppError(error));
    }
));}
```

**UPDATE**

a slight change is required to get this working properly as throw function implementation has also changed with rxjs6. now instead of throw error function from observable one have to use throwError() function. The implementation for the above task is as below.

```
  deletePost(id:number){
return this.http.delete(this._url+"/"+id)
.pipe(
  catchError(
    (error:Response)=>{
      if(error.status===404){
        console.log(error);
        return throwError(new NotFoundError(error));
      }
      return throwError(new AppError());
    }
));}
```

I hope someone will find this helpful and save few hours of their time. Cheers!

Comment: I'm here after watching Mosh Hamedani's tutorial. You are just a saviour.